# Dividing values in a column by the number of rows returned in the query. Can it be done in a single query?

Tags: mysql

Can I divide the values in a column by the number of rows returned in the query, using a single query?

For example, I select some numeric value from a table based on some condition:

```
select value from table where ...
```

Let's say it returns N rows and I want the returned values divided by the number of rows returned:

```
select value / N from table where ...
```

It can be done with several queries (e.g. after the first query, I query the number of rows and do the query again). But can it be done in a single query with some SQL trick without query condition duplication, so that the actual selection (the WHERE part) which may be complicated runs only once?

Comment: Likely no. MySQL does not support analytic functions (COUNT(*) over all rows). You would have to do a subquery count (which would run your select over the table a second time).

Comment: I was thinking about selecting the results first into some temporary table in a subqery and then counting its rows and selecting the results from there, but I don't know if it's possible to do this in a single query

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single query, but as far as I know, with mysql you have to repeat the condition:

```
select 
value/@cnt from 
table1 
INNER JOIN (select @cnt = count(*) 
 FROM table1 WHERE [the same condition as in main query]) ON (1=1)
WHERE condition
```

Or you can just

```
SELECT value/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE ...)
FROM table1 
WHERE ...
```

I believe optimizer should  generate the same execution plan for both queries.